# Get distinct month and year with SubSonic

Tags: subsonic, distinct, simplerepository

I have date type column (MySQL):

```
SELECT invdate FROM invoices;

invdate
-------
2009-08-22
2009-07-12
2009-08-23
-------
```

and I want get month and year like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(invdate) AS invmonth, YEAR(invdate) AS invyear FROM invoices;
```

how to use in C# with SubSonic (SimpleRepository)?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! I forgot to define variable as date/datetime, so I can not use these functions.

before:

```
public string invdate { get; set; }
```

after:

```
public DateTime invdate { get; set; }
```

My mistake, I'm sorry. **Problem solved**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a chance to have a look at the docs? See the link and code below, it should help.

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Distinct

```
[Test]
public void SqlQuery_when_setting_distinct_it_should_set_IsDistinct()
{
    SubSonic.SqlQuery query= new 
        Select(Product.SupplierIDColumn).From<Product>().Distinct();
    Assert.IsTrue(query.IsDistinct);
}

[Test]
public void SqlQuery_should_handle_distinct()
{
    ProductCollection select = new 
        Select(Product.SupplierIDColumn).From<Product>().Distinct()
        .ExecuteAsCollection<ProductCollection>();

    Assert.AreEqual(29, select.Count);

}

[Test]
public void SqlQuery_GetRecordCount_should_handle_distinct()
{
    int select = new Select(Product.SupplierIDColumn)
        .From<Product>().Distinct()
        .GetRecordCount();

    Assert.AreEqual(29, select);
}
```